# taking the address of temporary object

Tags: xcode

I'm developping on many platforms, today I have a problem with iOS and xCode,
I'm upadating some projects to the last xCode 4.3.2 (Apple LLVM compiler 3.1)

since few time **a warning has become an error: *"taking the address of temporary object"***

unfortunately I used many of that, see my example :

```
float dist = Vector3Dlength(&Vector3D(pos2 - pos1));
```

- to avoid to create a temporary var and produce a new line of code (although this one is created on the stack by the compiler)
- I know the mistakes that can lead since 10 years of coding like that :) but I WANT to continue like that...

someone have a suggestion to avoid this error without having to edit the code ? (with the new xCode 4.3.2 (Apple LLVM compiler 3.1))

Comment: Can you show the definition of Vector3Dlength?

Comment: float Vector3Dlength(Vector3D const* pvect)

Comment: That's the declaration. What does that function do with the pointer? Does it store it anywhere?

Comment: return SQRT((pvect->x * pvect->x) + (pvect->y * pvect->y) + (pvect->z * pvect->z));

Comment: Why can't you edit the code, given it's broken?

Comment: you talk about the constructor of Vector3D struct ? :)

Comment: @trojanfoe because I have many many (too many) of this type of error

Comment: @solilab: no, that's what I meant sorry. There's no good reason to be passing a pointer there, even less so for taking the address of a temporary. You'll need to update your code.

Comment: I use a pointer to prevent the entire structure to be copied localy to the function. a pointer = sizeof(void*) = 32bit VERSUS a sizeof(Vector3D) = 32bits * 3 = 96bits... I think it's faster via pointer, am i wrong ?

Comment: @solilab: I'm having a very grave doubt here: this _is_ C++, right? (Or Objective-C++)

Comment: in fact, a mix of two, I need to config all my cpp files to 'Objective-C++ compilation'

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your code, you can't take an address of something that is not an *lvalue*, and that temporary isn't one.

Change your code to take a const reference to `Vector3D` instead. This will not cost you a copy, and is well-defined behavior.

```
float Vector3Dlength(Vector3D const& pvect) {
  return sqrt(pvect.x * pvect.x ...);
}

...
float dist = Vector3Dlength(Vector3D(pos2 - pos1));
```

Comment: Agreed - why keep crap code in your codebase just avoid editing it?